# Question mark usage

Tags: swift

Here is the below function plz have look at return statement:

```
   private func escapeParameters(parameters:[String:AnyObject]) ->String{
        if parameters.isEmpty{
            return ""
        }else{
           var keyValuePairs = [String]()

            for(key,value)in parameters{

            //make sure that it is a string value
            let stringValue = "\(value)"

            //escape it
            let escapedValue = stringValue.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)

            //append it
            keyValuePairs.append(key + "=" + "\(escapedValue!)")
         }
            return "?\(keyValuePairs.joined(separator:"&"))"
     }
   }
```

**What does the question use for in that line?optional type in swift？**

```
return "?\(keyValuePairs.joined(separator:"&"))"
```

Comment: It simply returns a string starting with a question mark, there is no magic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks look the sample code used in Udacity's iOS developer course.

The question mark is used in URLs to pass parameters in a GET request.

for example:

http://example.com?userId=1234&name=John

Passes userId and name params. This is known as the query string. It's not specific to Swift, rather HTTP or the web in general